# How to reduce the delay of openign a select dropdown with a lot of options?

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have a record of nearly 50,000 names in a single table. I have a select dropdown box that has been populated with those names as options. But the problem is, I have been facing performance issue with it. That said, it takes nearly 2 seconds to open the dropdown. So, currently is definitely not a user friendly select box. How can I reduce this delay?

I have used the following `php` to populate the options.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "db");
$name = '';
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $name.= '<option value="' . $row["name"] . '">' . $row["name"] . '</option>';
    }
?>
```

What better solution should I look for to improve the performance? Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: Better use auto complete.

Comment: With that many names I wouldn't use a drop-down. Use a text field with autocomplete. IOW as the user types, use AJAX to find matches and display those to choose from. For an example, see [auto complete with jQuery](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/)

Comment: Thanks @SloanThrasher. I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @AlimonKarim I'm looking into it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Here's a better link: [jQuery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your effort @SloanThrasher. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: “Should not be used” - seems a little harsh